# Internet Connection Problem in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: internet

Guys I am new to Ubuntu but have learned basic usage. There is a problem, its connection to the internet. The problem is that my laptop does get connected to the WiFi, but internet connection does not get established. And its like sometime it gets connected sometime it does not. The only solution i found is disable network connection then again enable it and wait if it gets connected, and there is very less chance of you getting lucky. I am attaching all the pics which might help you understand the problem. There is a link which contains 5 images:

1. The Problem
2. lspci command on terminal
3. lspci -knn command on terminal
4. lspci -knn |grep Net -A2 command on terminal
5. The solution i tried(downloaded backport.zip file)

This link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ixqwN3AVM0bGFpVUg5LXFNZnM
Solution to this problem will be a great help, Ubuntu is awesome while coding, specially the work space thing, i want to continue working in Ubuntu, so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try disabling network manager and connect to it manually

```
systemctl stop network-manager.service
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 up
wpa_passphrahe "SSID" password > /etc/wpa.conf
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa.conf -Dwext && dhclient -r wlan0 && dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: Buddy u r asking me to disable the network manager, fine using your commands here maybe i can, but if the solution does not work then, how will i enable the network manager again, i am new to linux so i dont want to take risk until i am prepared with a solution.

Comment: its just temporary it will start at boot or just re-enable it using systemctl start network-manager.service just to see if the problem is with nm in my case a lot of times it was just that,and as i can see your drivers are OK whats the harm ?